# Factorize number into summands that are closest to each other

Tags: javascript, math

I want the summands to be as close to each other as possible.

x and y -> "y summands that are closest to each other"

15 and 2 -> 7+8

15 and 3 -> 5+5+5

15 and 4 -> 4+4+4+3

15 and 5 -> 3+3+3+3+3

15 and 6 -> 2+2+2+3+3+3

...

If I divide x/y and get a whole number, the solution is y times that whole number. But if I get a decimal it gets more complicated, as seen in the above example.

How can I calculate those "closest to each other summands" with any x and y preferably with javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the remainder of your division. It will tell you how often you need to round up the exact result of the division instead of rounding down.

```
function closest_summands(x, y) {
    var div = x / y,
        rem = x % y,
        res = [];
    for (var i=0; i<rem; i++)
        res.push( Math.ceil(div) );
    for (       ; i<y;   i++) // continue
        res.push( Math.floor(div) );
    return res;
}
```

Of course, you could make this a little more efficient by not repeating the `ceil`/`floor`-computations, I just wanted to show how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
function closest_summands(x, y) {
    var result = [],
        n = Math.floor(x / y),
        i, j;
    for (i = 0, j = x % y; i < y; i++, j--) {
        result.push(n + (j > 0 ? 1 : 0));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you subtract `Math.floor(x/y)*y` from `x` you could use [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to spread the remainder over the terms with a minimal spread.